# Using scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter to find stars in astro photo, but puzzled by results

Tags: image-processing, scipy

I am searching for stars in an umage of night sky, after making a mask I use scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter at different sizes to find the stars. It looks to work reasonably well, but I expected once I used a small enough size, I would just get more hits as I reduced the size further, but it doesn't do this consistently, **I am just a bit baffled by this.**

There is an extract from around one of the hit areas at the bottom

The code below gives me:

```
size: 3, len: 621
size: 4, len: 340
size: 5, len: 200
size: 6, len: 0
size: 7, len: 0
size: 8, len: 24
size: 9, len: 8
size: 10, len: 0
size: 11, len: 0
size: 12, len: 0
```

Why do size 6 & 7 give zero hits? This seems totally bizarre to me!

```
 def __init__(self, filename):
        self.good=False
        self.img = scipy.ndimage.imread(filename, flatten=True)

    def checkcandidates(self, meanfact=3.0, maxwindow=25):
        mask = self.img > self.img.mean()*meanfact
        for wsize in range(3,maxwindow):
            m2 = scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter(mask, size=wsize)
            xc,yc = m2.nonzero()
            print("size: %d, len: %d" %(wsize, len(xc)))
```

Here's part of the mask centred on one of the stars:

```
>>> sc1.showCoords(1360,493,10,usemask=True)    
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, or at least a nasty implementation detail that will result in bugs in users' code.

First, read the note in the [`uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html) docstring:

```
The multi-dimensional filter is implemented as a sequence of
one-dimensional uniform filters. The intermediate arrays are stored
in the same data type as the output. Therefore, for output types
with a limited precision, the results may be imprecise because
intermediate results may be stored with insufficient precision.
```

So let's look at how one row of your input array is processed by [`uniform_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter1d.html) for different size filters.

Here's a small one-dimensional input:

```
In [416]: x
Out[416]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Apply `uniform_filter1d` with increasing sizes:

```
In [417]: from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter1d

In [418]: uniform_filter1d(x, 3)
Out[418]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [419]: uniform_filter1d(x, 4)
Out[419]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [420]: uniform_filter1d(x, 5)
Out[420]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [421]: uniform_filter1d(x, 6)
Out[421]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [422]: uniform_filter1d(x, 7)
Out[422]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [423]: uniform_filter1d(x, 8)
Out[423]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [424]: uniform_filter1d(x, 9)
Out[424]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Like your example, the output is all zeros when the size is 6 or 7.

I suspect this is a floating point precision problem.  Note what happens when we make the input an array of floating point values:

```
In [439]: f = uniform_filter1d(x.astype(float), 6)

In [440]: f
Out[440]: 
array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.66666667e-01,   3.33333333e-01,   5.00000000e-01,
         6.66666667e-01,   8.33333333e-01,   1.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
         8.33333333e-01,   6.66666667e-01,   5.00000000e-01,
         3.33333333e-01,   1.66666667e-01,   5.55111512e-17,
         5.55111512e-17,   5.55111512e-17])

In [441]: f.max()
Out[441]: 0.99999999999999989
```

So the intermediate values computed using floating point do not give the expected value of 1 in the "middle" of that output.  When this array is converted back to the input data type (int), the result is all zeros:

```
In [442]: f.astype(int)
Out[442]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Given that behavior, I recommend converting your input array to floating point before calling `uniform_filter`, and adding a final step that converts the result back to integers in a way that *you* control, and that matches how you want to classify a "hit".  Or even use a different function altogether.

Comment: Aha, I had just experimented with 1D arrays and found this, was coming back to add a comment!. Strange though that it only happens (so far) with 6 & 7 and recovers again at 8. The code really should round though I believe.

Comment: Rather than convert the input array, creating a float array and using output param works well