# Applying rectangular step function using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a rectangular filter in scipy? I want to replicate @Mike T's solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/what-raster-smoothing-generalization-tools-are-available/162852 but nstead of doing gaussian blur, I want to apply a rectangular filter (i.e. essentially a step function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy-ndimage-filters-convolve) and define the `weights` (filter) yourself. There is also a specialized and optimized rectangular filter function: [`uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter)

For example to apply a width 3 mean-filter (multiply by `ndim*size` if you want a sum-filter):

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter
>>> uniform_filter([1,4,2,56,2,3,6,1,3,1,3], size=3)
array([ 2,  2, 20, 19, 20,  3,  3,  3,  1,  2,  2])
```

This can also be applied to multidimensional arrays:

```
>>> uniform_filter(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10, 10)), size=3)  # 3x3 filter
array([[ 6,  7, 10,  9,  9,  7,  5,  7,  9, 12],
       [ 6,  7,  9,  9,  7,  6,  5,  5,  7,  9],
       [ 5,  8,  8,  9,  7,  6,  4,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 9, 10,  9, 10,  8,  6,  4,  4,  8, 11],
       [10, 12,  9, 10,  9, 10,  8,  8,  9, 10],
       [12, 12,  9, 10, 10, 10,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [12, 11,  9,  8,  7,  8,  7,  8,  6,  5],
       [11, 10,  9,  9,  9,  9,  6,  8,  8,  9],
       [12,  9,  7,  7,  9,  8,  6,  6,  6,  8],
       [12,  9,  8,  9, 12, 10,  7,  5,  6,  9]])
>>> uniform_filter(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10, 10)), size=(5, 3))  # 5x3 filter
array([[ 7,  7,  8, 10, 11, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12],
       [ 7,  7,  7,  9, 10, 11, 11, 10,  9,  9],
       [ 7,  6,  6,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  8,  8],
       [ 6,  6,  6,  8,  8,  9,  8,  7,  7,  8],
       [ 8,  8,  7,  9,  8, 11,  8,  8,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  7,  9,  8, 11,  7,  7,  5,  7],
       [ 9,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  7,  7,  7,  8],
       [ 8,  8,  8,  9, 10, 10,  8,  7,  6,  6],
       [ 9,  7,  6,  8,  9, 10,  8,  7,  6,  6],
       [ 9,  6,  6,  7, 10,  8,  8,  6,  6,  6]])
```

Comment: FYI: Be careful when using `uniform_filter` with integer inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489650/using-scipy-ndimage-uniform-filter-to-find-stars-in-astro-photo-but-puzzled-by

Comment: In fact, you can see an example of the problem with integers in the result of `uniform_filter([1,4,2,56,2,3,6,1,3,1,3], size=3)`.  The value `19` in the result should be `20`.